Does histidine or other amino acids give sodium bicarbonate test?
Histidine, like other amino acids, has a carboxyl group which indicates that it will give sodium bicarbonate test, i.e. involving brisk effervescence of CO2 gas. However, I actually couldn't find much helpful information online. ChatGPT says that it would not give this test but did not include a proper explanation.

Does it really have carboxyl group? How do the present groups interact with each other? (Hint)

Histidine does have a carboxyl group. It is one of essential aminoacids. Histamine as decarboxylated histidine does not. // As it is basic aminoacid with imidazole ring, it will not probably give the test.

@Poutnik Tsk, tsk Oscar got my hint ;)

@Mithoron Hehe, the hint purpose could be little hidden to me and my mind is not always the brightest.  :-)

As sugested in the comments, it's easy to be fooled. Amino acids generally apppear to have the formula
$\ce{H2N – CH(R) – COOH},$
but the amino group is sufficiently basic to deprotonate the carboxyl group despite the resultant charge separation. Thus, in reality, the amino acid has the zwitterionic form
$\ce{H3\overset{+}{N} –CH(R) – CO2^-}$
in which the carboxyl group, having lost its proton, no longer can react with bicarbonate and the protonated amino group is too weakly acidic to do so. Thus the bicarbonate test fails (unless, as in some amino acids, the $\ce{R}$ group has a carboxyl group that does not get deprotonated or otherwise is sufficiently acidic to react on its own).
The protonated amino group can react with carbonate ion ($\ce{CO3^{2-}}$), which is a stronger base than bicarbonate ($\ce{HCO3^-}$). But that reaction stops at the bicarbonate stage and thus bubbling of carbon dioxide is not seen.
